# FLS Code Coverage issue

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage, crud, fls

**Need code coverage for my IF block**

```
 if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isCreateable()) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.FATAL,
                    'Insufficient access'));
            } else{

}
```

Any Help or Suggestion Plz.... !

Answer (score 0):

```
@IsTest public with sharing class classnameTest {
  public static void testclassname() {

     Test.StartTest();

    // set the test's page to  VF page (or pass in a PageReference)
    Test.setCurrentPage(Page.yourpage);//replace with our page name

    // Instantiate a new controller with all parameters in the page
    classname controller = new classname();
    controller.username = 'test@salesforce.com';


    ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().put('hasError','true');  

    List<Apexpages.Message> msgs = ApexPages.getMessages();
    boolean b = false;
    for(Apexpages.Message msg:msgs){
        if (msg.getDetail().contains('A user account for this email address already exists') b = true;
    }
    system.assert(b);//Assert the Page Message was Properly Displayed

    System.assertEquals(controller.methodname(),null); 
  }
}
```

I have drafted a rough version and that may help.Key is to set current page as your page for which you are testing and assert

Comment: I think Nilesh's problem is more specific than how to check the message: he needs to run the his test for a user that cannot create the field and for a user that can. This may require two profiles and two users and [System.runAs](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Testing_with_RunAs).